# maven: able to execute sonar goal for "post-integration-test" but not for "site" phase

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have a use-case where we want to do sonar analysis as part of site generation. That is whenever "mvn install site:site" is invoked, we want sonar:sonar to be invoked as well as part of that.

We tried following plugin configuration, but that doesn't work to execute sonar goal as part of site phase (we tried "pre-site" phase too but that did not work as well):

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.603</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>sonar-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>sonar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
<build>
```

Just for experimenting, when we changed: `<phase>site</phase>` to `<phase>post-integration-test</phase>` in the above snippet, sonar goal started getting executed after IT execution.

Is there something wrong in compatibility between sonar-maven-plugin and maven-site-plugin. Will appreciate any input or alternate approach to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You bound the SonarQube Maven plugin to a `site` phase, but you didn't execute that phase. You passed `site:site` which means `execute a site goal of the maven-site-plugin`.

You have to execute: `mvn install site`

The solution with `post-integration-test` works, because that stage is executed by `install` phase (more or less).

Read more about [Maven Lifecycle Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).